# Lagrangian particle tracking for already solved flows (post-processing mode)

Tags: post-processing, openfoam

I am trying to run the  particle tracking solver icoUncoupledKinematicParcelFoam in post-processing (I already have the flow files). Do you know where I can find some tutorial if any?

I have already solved a flow case such as pitzDaily.

I myCase/constant folder I have included kinematicCloudProperties and kinematicCloudPositions.

I would like to compute the particles tracking in my domain.
Do you have any suggestion?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

this questions is largely off-topic here (stackoverflow) because it's about *using* OpenFOAM, not *programming* OpenFOAM. A more on-topic forum is cfd-online.com's OpenFOAM forums: 
Home > Forums > Software User Forums > OpenFOAM > OpenFOAM Running, Solving & CFD
.

Have you taken a look at `OpenFOAM-x.x/tutorials/lagrangian/icoUncoupledKinematicParcelFoam/hopper` tutorial? Additionally, Chalmer's [CFD with Open Source](http://www.tfd.chalmers.se/~hani/kurser/OS_CFD/) Software course usually has some neat notes, e.g. [here](http://www.tfd.chalmers.se/~hani/kurser/OS_CFD_2014/Efstratios_Fonias/Documents/RevisedTutorial_LESchannelParticles.pdf). You may be able to find something helpful there.

Good luck.